# Basic Python socket communications questions; working with netcat

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

First let me say that I am not a programmer but I have always been able to accomplish what I've needed with Python.  My current project is a network encoder for SageTV.  SageTV PVR sends commands to a network encoder running on port 4510 which in turn tunes a capture card, then starts ffmpeg recording based on parameters passed.  It then continues to listen for further instructions and processes those commands.

I have set up SageTV and can communicate using netcat.  This is the output using netcat:

```
root@debian# nc -l -k -p 4510
VERSION
1
STOP
OK
```

In the above example.  The SageTV server replied 'VERSION' and I typed '1' then it replied 'STOP' and I replied 'OK'.

I have been trying to find a good example of how to convert what netcat is doing into a Python script.  I've found various examples but I just can't find one that will listen and even just show what the server is showing.  Can someone show me or point me to a good example?  I know this should be really easy to do but I've been banging my head on this with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with [`socket(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) to get an idea of what netcat is actually doing.  Then take a *brief* look at [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) before continuing on to [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and/or [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver).

Answer (score 2):

Examle code using python3 and asyncio:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def handler(reader, writer):
    def send(msg):
        print("send to device: {}".format(msg))
        writer.write((msg + '\n').encode())

    print("device connected")
    while True:
        msg = yield from reader.readline()
        if not msg:
            print("device disconnected")
            break
        msg = msg.decode().strip()
        print("got from device: {}".format(msg))

        if msg == 'VERSION':
            send('1')
        elif msg == 'STOP':
            send('OK')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handler, '0.0.0.0', 4510, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

For documentation start from https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed.  If I may trouble you with only one more thing.  The server replies back with a windows path like this:

BUFFER SageSlingBox-1 TV Tuner|3|83886080|D:\Media\tvrecordings\SageSlingBox1on1921680204510TVTuner-0.mpgbuf|Best

I am trying to pull the filepath out of this jumble but I'm having a world of difficulty as it sees the \tvrecordings as \t vrecordings.  Tab vrecordings.  Any idea on how to sanitize msg?  I tried replacing the \ with / but I can't get that to work.

Comment: use escaping by doubling \\: `\\tvrecordings`